# how to give action to progress bar

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iphone. what i am doing is cretating a imageview and a progressview i create iboutlet for both imageview and progressview and take a timer after 4 min i will call imagepicker.All is well but the progressview is no action only display as idle i am writing code for that is `progressview.progress=0.0; [self.view addsubview.progrssview];`
really i dont know how it solve pls help me .

Comment: I think there is a syntax error on the code you added it should be like that [self.view addSubview:progrssview];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call a method with NSTimer and in the method, change the value of `progressview.progress=0.0` to a value between 0.0 and 1.0. e.g. if you want to show the progress bar for 5 mins, set a timer with a timeInterval of say, 3 seconds and increase the progress value by 0.01.

Answer (score 2):

```
-(IBAction) method{

timer =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self 
        selector:@selector(method) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

progressView.progress = actual + 0.05;
}
```